# Twig Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected tag

Tags: php, symfony, twig

This is my first time using Twig and I am have a weird error where I am getting this:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected "post" tag (expecting closing tag for the "for" tag defined near line 21). in /code/site3/views/index/index.twig.php on line 22
```

My code is the following:

```
//Setup The Twig Environment
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/code/site3/views/');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

    //Display The Template
    echo $twig->render('/index/index.twig.php', array('posts' => array('title' => 'A Title', 'content' => 'Abc 123')));
```

And my html is this:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            {% for post in posts %}
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <a href="/posts/view/{% post.post_id %}"> <h2 class="post-title"> {% post.title %}</h2> <h3 class="post-subtitle">  {% post.content %} </h3> </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">
                        Posted by <a href="/profile/{% post.user_id %}">{% post.user.first_name %} {% post.user.last_name %}</a>
                        on {% post.date_created %}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <hr>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

What am I potentially missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you mixing up Twig syntax `{% .. %}` is used for flow control like `for` and `if` functions and `{{ .. }}` is used for "echoing".

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            {% for post in posts %}
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <a href="/posts/view/{{ post.post_id }}"> <h2 class="post-title"> {{ post.title }}</h2> <h3 class="post-subtitle">  {{ post.content }} </h3> </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">
                        Posted by <a href="/profile/{{ post.user_id }}">{{ post.user.first_name }} {{ post.user.last_name }}</a>
                        on {{ post.date_created }}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <hr>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

The `{% .. %}` syntax is used to execute statements, the `{{ .. }}` syntax prints the result of an expression to the template.